# Laravel5.5 redirect back() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application that i have been working on for awhile , the problem i am facing now is that when validation fails on any form including the default registration and login forms or ust a redirect back after any process, the site redirects to '/' (the home route) instead of redirecting back to the previous page. i have tried clearing cache but that didn't help.

The application works fine on local machine, also i have a middleware that enforces secure urls on production environment

```
if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') { return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri()); }
```

Comment: `dump $request->getRequestUri()` and see where the url leads to

Comment: It displays the current link for example "/dashboard"

Comment: If you are using Laravel built in login/register, then look at `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and override specific methods like `sendLoginResponse`

Comment: What is the app url in the .env file?

Comment: @NikolaGavric overriding the login/register methods did not work

Comment: What are your `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @Tarasovych `php artisan route:list` returns nothing although the routes work, i have run `route:clear` and `route:cache` same issue persists

Comment: @user3246946 are you sure you are using 5.5? `route:list` might return all routes

Comment: @Tarasovych yes i'm using 5.5 , it should return all routes but it is not , also `php artisan ` returns nothing but other commands work just fine

Comment: So i found out the package that is causing the problem (secure-headers) https://github.com/mikefrancis/laravel-secureheaders .
When i remove its global middleware the app works fine.
Problem is i still need to use that package to set secure headers for my application